# The plus and addition of tensor vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose there is a vector space $V$ with basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. Denote $V$ tensor $V$ as $V\otimes V$, with basis$\{(e_1\otimes e_1),(e_1\otimes e_2),(e_2\otimes e_1),(e_2\otimes e_2)\}$.
Then the vectors $(e_2\otimes e_1)-(e_1\otimes e_2),(e_1\otimes e_2)-(e_2\otimes e_1) \in V\otimes V$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: One is just $-1$ times the other...

Comment: Then what about $(e_2\otimes e_1)-(e_1\otimes e_2)-(e_1\otimes e_2)+(e_2\otimes e_1)$ and $(e_2\otimes e_1)-(e_1\otimes e_2)$? I'm confused about whther I can have some thing like: $2(e_2\otimes e_1)-2(e_1\otimes e_2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\{e_1\otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2\}$ is a basis of $V \otimes V$, then every $v \in V$ can be written as
$$v = k_1(e_1\otimes e_1) + k_2(e_1 \otimes e_2) + k_3 (e_2 \otimes e_1) + k_4 (e_2 \otimes e_2).$$

This means, particularly, that you **can** have something like $2(e_2 \otimes e_1) - 2(e_1 \otimes e_2)$. Actually, most vectors in $V \otimes V$ are not homogeneous tensors (i.e., tensors of the form $v \otimes w$).

To answer you original question, as pointed out by @MichaelMorrow, $e_2 \otimes e_1 - e_1 \otimes e_2 = -(e_1 \otimes e_2 - e_2 \otimes e_1)$, thus $\{e_2 \otimes e_1 - e_1 \otimes e_2, e_1 \otimes e_2 - e_2 \otimes e_1\}$ is a linearly dependent set.